# How to buy with ethers js using Uniswap Universal router on Base? calling execute function

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, uniswap, nodejs, uniswapv3

I want to buy new tokens launched on base using Uniswap Universal router on Base with node js and ether js libraries. Im calling execute function but I'm having many problems.

Here is the code:

```
//addresses
const WETH = '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006' // WETH base

// const tokenToBuy = '0xe67aB9Efb46d987d2aF816597F6716069A8a7426' //KIF

//Router
const routerAddress = '0x198EF79F1F515F02dFE9e3115eD9fC07183f02fC' // router
const file = fs.readFileSync("./B_Base/ABIUniversal.json", 'utf8') // Calls sushi ABI
const routerAbi = JSON.parse(file)
const routerContract = new ethers.Contract(routerAddress, routerAbi, signer)

// token input
const prompt = ps()
const tokenToBuy = String(prompt("Enter token name: ")) 

//wbnb to spend
const spend = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0001")

const commands = 0x00

const path = [AbiCoder.encode(WETH), AbiCoder.encode(5000), AbiCoder.encode(tokenToBuy)]

 // Encode the parameters
const inputs = AbiCoder.encode(WALLET_ADDRESS, spend, 0, path, false)

const buy = async () => { // .execute execute(bytes commands,bytes[] inputs,uint256 deadline)
    const buy = await routerContract.execute(
      commands,
      inputs,
      Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 10)
      
    receipt = await buy.wait()
    transactionHash = receipt.transactionHash
    console.log(transactionHash)
    
}


buy()
```

There is an error when encoding the path and input to call the execute function. I don't understand the error is showing me I have been following ethers documentation and Uniswap docs too.

Error:

```
if (types.length !== values.length) {
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at AbiCoder.encode (/home/oriok/DEV/degen/Arbitrum/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/abi-coder.js:82:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/oriok/DEV/degen/Arbitrum/B_Base/testinUni.js:52:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other router that allows you to buy any kind of token? I have been using SwapRouterV2 but doesnt allow me to buy some tokens.